# Django queryset on floating point range

Tags: python, django, floating-point, django-queryset

I came through a problem which I never happened to face before in Django queryset. I have more then 1,00,000 of floating point datatype (records) along with foreign key field in one data model class. What I am trying to do is query on these records with following procedure.

- User will enter value (v) e.g 1248.597290039063(float point) and filter like preicison (f) (how many digits to accept after decimal). If precision is 5 then I will take only 5 numbers after decimal point, e.g (1248.59729).  I will get these request from html template and do rest operation on the view.
- Default parameter ( p) =  0,000005
- new value (nv) =  p* v
- Highest range (HR) = v + nv
- Lowest range (LR) = v- nv
- Now, HR and LR is the search space where query should be done.

So, please only focus on querying on such **range** after **decimal point (fixed)** ?

If question is not clear enough please do comment. I will again try my best.

Guide me

Answer (score 8):

If you have the high and low ends of your range already computed, then you can use a simple range query in Django:

```
objects = my_model.objects.filter(field__gte=LR, field__lte=HR)
```

or, somewhat shorter:

```
objects = my_model.objects.filter(field__range=(LR, HR))
```

(You'll have to replace 'my_model' and 'field' with your actual model and field names, of course)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain quite well. But I want to get all values that lies in the range of highest and lowest frequency. I think your filtering shows only two highest and lowest one.

Comment: No, this filter should show _all_ objects with a 'field' value between the two range endpoints; that's what the '__gte', '__lte', and '__range' operators do.